# Sum of products of binomial coefficients.

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

If $(1+x+x^2)^n= \Sigma_{r=0}^{2n}a_r x^r$ then $a_r- \binom n1 a_{r-1}+\binom n2 a_{r-2}-\binom n3 a_{r-3}+....+(-1)^r\binom nr a_{0} $ is equal to (r is not a multiple of 3)

Options

a)0

b) $^nC_r$

c) $a_r$

d)1

There's no way I can think of to get an expression like that. I tried differentiating to see whether it could help me or not but it was in vain. Please help me out of this problem.

Comment: What did you try? It is usually not well received to ask an exam question without any attempt at solving it. Do you know what the answer is for $n=1,2,3$ ?

Comment: @charmd the answer given in the book is 0. I have also tried multiplying $(1+x)^n$ with $(1+x+x^2)^n$ and get the coefficients of $x^r$  in it but it was of no use.

Comment: Have you tried a proof by induction?

Comment: I suppose this is a particular case of expansion $(a_0 + \, \cdots \, + a_{k-1})^n$. I also do not know the answer for this expansion.

Comment: I have solved it! I don't know why it didn't appear in my mind the expression given is the coefficient of $x^r$ in$(1-x)^n (1+x+x^2)^n$ which simplifies to $(1-x^3)^n$. thus the coefficient of $x^r$ is 0. Sorry, I forgot to mention in the question that $r$ is not a multiple of 3.